# Replace last characters of a string if it meets criteria

Tags: r, regex, while-loop

I have a vector of strings:

```
asdf <- c("a^sdf^", "asdf^^")
```

Now i want to remove the last element of both strings, but only if that last element is a ^, resulting in:

```
[1] "a^sdf"  "asdf"
```

I tried:

```
function1 <- function(x){
  while(any(substr(x, nchar(x) - 1 + 1, nchar(x)) == "^")){
    x <- gsub(".{1}$", "", x)
  }
  return(x)
}
function1(asdf)
[1] "a^sd"  "asdf"
```

As you can see the first string is reduced to more than ^ at the end. I tried experimenting with if conditions in combination to the while loop but it didn't work out. What is missing so that only the ^ gets removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, using `stringr::str_remove`:

```r
library(stringr)

str_remove(asdf, "\\^+$")

#> [1] "a^sdf" "asdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can think of them as a whitespace and use base *trimws* - trim whitespace:

```
trimws(asdf, which = "right", whitespace = "\\^")
# [1] "a^sdf" "asdf"
```